# Array in generics declaration in Swift

Tags: swift

I came from Kotlin/Java to swift. I can't find anywhere how to make smth like

```
let response: InspResponse<[Album]>
```

I get an error message from xcode - `response requires that '[Album]' be a class type`

How can I specify response of list of objects in swift generics?

Where as response is an Objective C class compiled from Kotlin native

```
__attribute__((swift_name("InspResponse")))
@interface MusicFeatureInspResponse<T> : MusicFeatureBase
@end;

__attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted))
__attribute__((swift_name("InspResponseData")))
@interface MusicFeatureInspResponseData<T> : MusicFeatureInspResponse<T>
- (instancetype)initWithData:(T _Nullable)data __attribute__((swift_name("init(data:)"))) __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer));
@property (readonly) T _Nullable data __attribute__((swift_name("data")));
@end;
```

I need an equivalent of kotlin `val response: Reponse<List<Album>>` in swift 5

Comment: Show your `Response` definition.

Comment: Don’t name your generic type Data since that is a built in type in swift and might lead to confusion (both for you and the compiler)

Comment: It's fine. It's `Response.Data`, not `Foundation.Data`. That's what namespacing is for. It's just not ingrained in the  developer collective mindset yet.

Comment: Downvote because your code doesn't reproduce the error; can't help without that requirement being satisfied.

Comment: I have edited the question. Maybe there was error because Reponse was actually an objective c class

Answer (score 0):

For single:

```swift
let response = Response<Album>()
```

For array:

```swift
let response = Response<[Album]>()
```

See [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) for details.

Comment: But that's not what I need. I need to have Response of Array of Albums. Not just of 1 album.

Comment: Your code in question works for me, which version of swift exactly did you use?

Comment: I use swift 5. And the last - for array doesnt work for me. It says - response requires that '[Album]' be a class type

Comment: Generic in swift and objc are completely different, do not try to mix them. Swift won't do that bridge to objc AFAIK.